# Comparison of the topology induced by Hilbert-Schmidt norm and Operator norm

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

We know that the class of Hilbert-Schmidt operators $\mathcal{L}_2 \mathcal{(H)}$ on a Hilbert Space $\mathcal{H}$ forms a Hilbert Space with the inner product $\langle u,v\rangle =\operatorname{tr}(v^*u)$, where the trace function is defined for Trace-Class Operators by
$$\operatorname{tr}(u)=\sum_{x\in E}\langle ux,x \rangle$$
where $E$ is an orthonormal basis of $\mathcal{H}$. The norm for this topology is the Hilbert-Schmidt norm $\Vert u\Vert_2=\sum_{x\in E} \Vert u(x)\Vert ^2$. We also know that the operator norm $\Vert \cdot \Vert \leq \Vert \cdot \Vert_2$, which implies the Hilbert-Schmidt norm topology is weaker than the operator norm topology.

My question is whether the Hilbert-Schmidt norm topology is strictly weaker than the operator norm topology or whether they are equivalent on $\mathcal{L}_2 \mathcal{(H)}$?

Comment: Part 1 / 2: In the infinite-dimensional case, the Hilbert-Schmidt norm topology is strictly stronger$-$not weaker$-$than the operator norm topology:
Equip the Hilbert-Schmidt operators $\mathcal L _2(\mathcal H)$ with the subspace topology induced by the operator norm topology.
Then $\big(\mathcal L _2(\mathcal H),\Vert\cdot\Vert_\text{op}\big)
\stackrel{id}{\longrightarrow}\big(\mathcal L _2(\mathcal H),\Vert\cdot\Vert_2\big)$
is  $\:$n o t$\:$ continuous as @Mindlack 's answer demonstrates. Thus, not every
$\Vert\cdot\Vert_2$-open set is $\Vert\cdot\Vert_\text{op}$-open.

Comment: Part 2 / 2: The reverse map
$$\big(\mathcal L _2(\mathcal H),\Vert\cdot\Vert_2\big)
\stackrel{id}{\longrightarrow}
\big(\mathcal L _2(\mathcal H),\Vert\cdot\Vert_\text{op}\big)$$
is continuous which is equivalent to
$\Vert\cdot\Vert_\text{op} \leqslant \Vert\cdot\Vert_2$. In other words,
$\Vert\cdot\Vert_\text{op}$-open sets are also $\Vert\cdot\Vert_2$-open.
You may visit this [very similar post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3413051/316749).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the separable case (ie $E$ countable), it’s not. Consider an explicit bijection $E \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$, and let $V_n$ be the vector subspace generated by the first $n$ vectors of $E$. Let $T_n$ be $n^{-1/2}$ times the orthogonal projection on $V_n$. Then $\|T_n\|_{HS}=1$ but $\|T_n\|_{op}=n^{-1/2}$.

Comment: For the separable case, this is perfect. Do you have any idea about the non-separable case?

Comment: I think the same trick works.